# What is the difference between "lose to someone" and "lose out to someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *lose to someone* and *lose out to someone*? For example:

> Hassan **lost out** **to** his brother in the finals of the tennis tournament.

This example is from the book *English Phrasal Verbs in Use* by McCarthy M. and O'Dell F.

How would the meaning of the sentence change if it were *lose to*? For example:

> Hassan **lost to** his brother in the finals of the tennis tournament.

Comment: Usually, "losing out" means missing an opportunity, although [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lose_out) seems to think it means "lose".

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. In practice it makes no real difference to the meaning in the cited context here, but *some people* (including me) might well think including that optional extra preposition *(**out**)* puts a bit more emphasis on the fact that Hassan ***failed to gain*** all the good things that winning would have brought, whereas the simpler (and ***way*** more common) second version simply reports the result of the match. .

Comment: A team can "lose out" to another team without actually playing them, if a championship (or a promotion) depends on points.

Comment: It is a tricky question. Between those phrasal verbs, there exists a nuance. "Lose out to" commonly uses in a competition, while "lose out" means "be unsuccessful or suffer a loss". To this end, as there is a tournament, then it is better "lose out to" is used.